# Wikidata do not return me itemLabel sometimes

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am looking for people of french nationality born in 1900 (and still living). I do not well understand the behaviour of wikidata in response to my following request:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?item wdt:P569 ?dateOfBirth.
  ?item  wdt:P27 wd:Q142.
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?item wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}
  FILTER("1900-00-00"^^xsd:dateTime <= ?dateOfBirth &&  ?dateOfBirth < "1901-00-00"^^xsd:dateTime)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],fr". }
}
```

1. I do not understand why the folowing request do not return itemLabel for some rows; for example the itemlabel returned for https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q47508624 is its "id": Q47508624

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `wikibase:language` option, you're asking for Wikidata to provide you with the labels for each `?item` in the `?itemLabel` variable. You've requested that it provide you labels in either the language preferred by your browser (`[AUTO_LANGUAGE]`) or French (`fr`). I would guess that your browser's default language is French also. With a browser set with English as the default, I get "Hugues Esquerre" as the `?itemLabel` value for `wd:Q47508624` (this record has labels defined in English and Spanish).

You can add additional acceptable languages in the comma-separated list in the query to increase the liklihood of getting label values back:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?item wdt:P569 ?dateOfBirth.
  ?item  wdt:P27 wd:Q142.
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?item wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}
  FILTER("1900-00-00"^^xsd:dateTime <= ?dateOfBirth &&  ?dateOfBirth < "1901-00-00"^^xsd:dateTime)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],fr,en,es". }
}
```